# Angular Select with Large dataset

Tags: angular, firebase

I have an angular app that is using firebase to lookup a large dataset. I've to show a dropdown to the user with possibly 20k objects to the user.

What are some of the best practices to do such task without losing performance?

I've tried some third party dropdown components like: [ngx-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-select-ex) and [ngx-bootstrap's typeahead](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/). Everything results in freezing my web page.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to achieve such functionality without losing performance.

Comment: You must use an autocomplete API with lazy loaded searched list, when user have stopped typing.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45081212/lazy-load-firebase). It shows a technique mentioned by @Prachi for lazy loading. You basically limit the set that comes in, and use a flag to signal the end of the set in order to fetch more information.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50376838/9766215) might help you.

Comment: @Prachi Personally, I hate most implementation of what you describe. Most implementations attempt to autocomplete/act on what's being typed in real-time (i.e. as the user types rather than waiting for a pause). This often causes applications to freeze when having to deal with a large dataset. At a minimum, they need to do what you have mentioned and wait for the user to stop typing. In addition, such implementations should monitor how much time it's taking to complete what they are doing and allow other actions to be performed by the user (which may invalidate what it's currently doing).

Comment: @Makyen What is your recommended way of coping with such situation?

Comment: @Subhan The minimum that I've found useful is that the application should wait for a pause in what the user is typing. Most of such things that I've done have been hacks on top of other implementations in order to make my life more convenient (e.g. here on SE, I implement something like for text input boxes to prevent a noticeable delay caused by the preview renderer being called at least three times for each character input). When implementing a hack like this, I usually wait for at least a 200ms to 500ms pause in what the user is typing (depending on the implementation).

Comment: However, a better implementation would be adaptive both to the patterns of how the current user provides input (e.g. what length of pauses do you normally see from *this* user); and to how long the processing that you're doing actually takes between when you start and the display is updated for the user. The longer that it takes to accomplish the computing and update that's desired/needed, the longer the pause needs to be from the user.

Comment: Probably the best way to do this would be to implement the task in an interruptible thread that doesn't block user input. That way, you could start/restart the processing with each user input and have the update available to the user as soon as possible (as near to real-time as possible), while not preventing the user from using the user interface.

Answer (score 0):

you could implement this using a predefined set of options to start with. the user could then click on more to see further options, which would then be lazily loaded and further as he scrolls down, the options could be then lazily loaded again.
what i mean to say is bring chunks of data rather than populating the entire data at once. you could also implement autocomplete to facilitate searching. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what kind of performances you're talking about.

If it's about the request time, don't worry, firebase is scalable and pretty powerful.

If it's about the user's network performance, you should return only a subset of the results and paginate (firebase allows that).

If it's about displaying the results, you can use pagination or infinite scrolling.

Finally, you should explain your issue a little bit more, like the format of your data or what you're trying to achieve (from the user's perspective) if you want a more complete answer.